# Failed to resolve: com.github.androidmads:QRGenerator:1.0.3

Tags: java, android, android-studio, gradle, qr-code

I am new to Android and I am trying to create a QR code but when I add the library in gradle I get: **Failed to resolve: com.github.androidmads:QRGenerator:1.0.3**

The project has just been created but I could not find any solution to make it work. What could be the solution for this?

The code in my grade is:

```
    plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
}

ext {
    qrgeneratorVersion = qrgeneratorVersion
}
android {
    namespace 'com.example.androidqrpayment'
    compileSdk 33

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.androidqrpayment"
        minSdk 24
        targetSdk 33
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    buildFeatures {
        viewBinding true
    }
}

dependencies {

    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.4.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.5.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.3'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment:2.5.2'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-ui:2.5.2'
    implementation 'com.github.androidmads:QRGenerator:1.0.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.3'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.4.0'

}
```

Comment: Have you added Jitpack to your list of repositories, as described in the setup instructions? https://github.com/androidmads/QRGenerator#how-to-import-the-library

Comment: It did not work to add Jitpack in allprojects as reccomended but to add it to root settings.gradle, here: dependencyResolutionManagement

Comment: Having the repositories in settings.gradle is the new project layout used by AS for new projects. Originally everything was located in build.gradle.

Answer (score 0):

You're getting this error because you're trying to fetch a version of the library[1.0.3] which doesn't exist.

The latest stable version is v1.0.1, as per the lib repo.
https://github.com/androidmads/QRGenerator/releases/tag/1.0.1